# FT232H direct reset pin VCCIO connection

Tags: power, digital-logic, pcb-design, usb

According to the [datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232H.pdf), on p.19, it is stated that:

> RESET# should be tied to VCCIO(+3.3V) if not being used.

Same applies to SIWU# as well. Since I will not be using both of those pins, I would like to proceed like that.

Is it possible that connecting directly to VCCIO, without any resistor or capacitor, may lead to potential problems (e.g. accidental resets) or am I just over paranoid?

The board is 4 layer with dedicated ground, voltage planes. Final version will be enclosed to a shield (have not decided on material yet) but prototypes/dev boards will be plain.

Comment: Yap, you are over concerned. Just do what the datasheet says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that connecting directly to VCCIO, without any resistor
> or capacitor, may lead to potential problems (e.g. accidental resets)
> or am I just over paranoid?

Accidental resets would happen if you put a resistor between Reset and VCC, as it would be a very weak pull-up.

Using a capacitor in parallel (aka to reset and GND) like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV9noQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

would be a good idea to avoid reset issues due to high frequency external noise, but you should already have a capacitor close to the VCC pin, so you dont need to place a second cap there.